# maven - exclude dependency only from jar

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies

My project generates a jar and a dll (with ikvm). I need a dependency for the dll but I don't want it to be included in the jar, is it possible to do it ?

Comment: Can you please add more details?

Comment: In fact the dependency is another project that contains classes that I want in my dll... But I really don't want these classes in my jar. I just realized ikvm uses the generated jar to create de dll, so I think I'm going to have to generate 2 different jars from the same pom... But I know it's evil ! Is there another way ?

Comment: Use a classifier for the generated dll artifact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven Optional Dependencies.
While declaring a dependency, use `<optional>true</optional>`

Read more [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)